# Is there any way to access object itself while destructuring it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As a good example, consider react component like this:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {}
```

In the above component, we can access to the children of props like this:

```
const MyComponent = ({count, value, ...rest}) => {}
```

And using ...rest, we can have unlisted children, too.

**my question** is that is there any way to access *all of the children* with and without using **props**? something like this:

```
const MyComponent = ({count, value } = props) => { // I know this is wrong, it's just an example 
     return <>{props.count} {value} {props.someThingNotListed} </>  
     // getting able to access to destructed child direclty or by using props if we want
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with just doing `const { count, value } = props;` as the first line of the function body?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, with your second snippet, you still have access to everything in the object, so not sure what else you'd want. This feels a bit like an XY problem

Comment: @RobinZigmond I know it, I mean is there any way to do it in parameters...

Comment: @DerekPollard yeah, but as I explained in the 3rd snippet, I'm looking a way to access with and without props.

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani No, there is not.